# Annotating a value in Django using Extract and OuterRef (or F) leads to TypeError

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, orm, django-orm

I'm building an application where users can create posts. If the user don't post anything after some specific time of the day, the server will send a push notification to remember the user to post something.

In order to create this query I planned to run a scheduled celery beat task to filter the posts created in the current day, list the user's id and use a simply exclude these IDs from the active users in order to get a queryset with the users that should be notified.

The user has a timezone field, which is updated via a middleware that checks some headers frontend send, checks the user saved timezone and update it if necessary.

This timezone is the result of running the tzname() method in the datetime that comes in this header.

The issue is that the users are spread across multiple timezones, so I need to actually annotate the `created_at` field in Posts (which are saved taking in consideration the server timezone) with the User's timezone.

In Django we have the [Extract function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/database-functions/#extract) that simply does exactly what I need. The issue here is that it would work perfectly if I could use a F expression or OuterRef in order to use the user's saved timezone, like this:

`posts = Post.objects.annotate(timezoned_creation=Extract('created_at', 'hour', tzinfo=ZoneInfo(F('owner__timezone'))))`

But running this (the same happens if changing F with OuterRef) results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/zoneinfo/_tzpath.py", line 67, in find_tzfile
    _validate_tzfile_path(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/zoneinfo/_tzpath.py", line 80, in _validate_tzfile_path
    if os.path.isabs(path):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/posixpath.py", line 62, in isabs
    s = os.fspath(s)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not F
```

I understand that the issue here is that the F and OuterRef expressions are computed by SQL and not Django, but I have no idea how can I actually create this query in order to use extract and solve my problem.

Any ideas? (btw the DB is Postgres)

Comment: I was able to do it using RawSQL, but this would no be the ideal.

`sql = RawSQL("""EXTRACT('hour' FROM "posts_post"."created_at" AT TIME ZONE (SELECT U0."timezone" FROM "users_user" U0 WHERE U0."id" = ("posts_post"."owner_id")))""", ())`

`Post.objects.annotate(timezoned_creation=sql)`

Still can't understand what I'm doing wrong in the Outer ref expression...